# Relation between GCP project and OAuth app

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth

Trying to set up an OAuth flow for my web service so that it is able to access GCP services and I am not.

When going to the Credentials Service, there seems to be the option of having only ONE “OAuth Consent Screen”.

However, one can issue multiple OAuth Client IDs.

Does this just imply a mandatory 1-1 mapping  with an OAuth App and a GCP Project?

Answer (score 1):

An OAuth App (Client ID and Client Secret) is created in a project and is tied to that project for the purposes of management and control.

However, the identities that authenticate using that OAuth app are not tied to a single project. IAM within each project controls who/what can access resources.

A precise answer requires more details such as who is the OAuth Identity Provider (Google, Google Workspace, Google Identity Platform, etc.) and what resources and services the app grants access to.